# How can I clone a Vec<Box<dyn Trait>>?

Tags: rust

I want to implement a function that takes an immutable `&Vec` reference, makes a copy, sorts the values and prints them.

This is the main code.

```
trait Foo {
    fn value(&self) -> i32;
}

struct Bar {
    x: i32,
}

impl Foo for Bar {
    fn value(&self) -> i32 {
        self.x
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a: Vec<Box<dyn Foo>> = Vec::new();
    a.push(Box::new(Bar { x: 3 }));
    a.push(Box::new(Bar { x: 5 }));
    a.push(Box::new(Bar { x: 4 }));

    let b = &a;
    sort_and_print(&b);
}
```

The only way I was able to make it work was this

```
fn sort_and_print(v: &Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>) {
    let mut v_copy = Vec::new();
    for val in v {
        v_copy.push(val);
    }
    v_copy.sort_by_key(|o| o.value());
    for val in v_copy {
        println!("{}", val.value());
    }
}
```

However I want to understand what's happening here and also to make the code shorter.

##### Question 1

If I try to change `let mut v_copy = Vec::new();` to `let mut v_copy: Vec<Box<dyn Foo>> = Vec::new();` however that results in various errors that I don't know how to fix.

How do I make this version work and why is it different than the first version?

##### Attempt 2

Something closer to what I'm looking for is something like this.
`let mut v_copy = v.clone();` but this doesn't work. Can this version be fixed?

Comment: You can shorten the copying using `let mut v_copy: Vec<_> = v.iter().collect()`. A better question is why you need dynamic dispatch to begin with, when you're only putting one type in the `Vec`? That would [get rid of boxes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c9cc44d6177af99ef285746673d91518). You could also give a value-getting closure to `sort_and_print`, and completely get rid of the trait: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0657ffcad6e4a78c1b73917d4f7f22c4

Comment: I posted the simplified the code. The real code uses different structs that all implement the `Foo` trait.

Thanks for the code, it works! So we are actually creating a `Vec<&Box<dyn Foo>>` and not a `Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>`, but that’s not an issue. This also answered Question 1.

So is `.iter().collect()` the standard approach in these types of situations?

Comment: Yes, your code was always creating a `Vec<&Box<dyn Foo>>`, and `.iter().collect()` is just a more succinct way of doing it. `let x: Vec<_> = <some iterator>.collect()` is a standard Rust idiom for creating a vector for something you iterate over.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, let's annotate the types:

```rust
fn sort_and_print(v: &Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>) {
    let mut v_copy: Vec<&Box<dyn Foo>> = Vec::new();
    for val /* : &Box<dyn Foo> */ in v {
        v_copy.push(val);
    }
    v_copy.sort_by_key(|o: &&Box<dyn Foo>| <dyn Foo>::value(&***o));
    for val /* : &Box<dyn Foo> */ in v_copy {
        println!("{}", <dyn Foo>::value(&**val));
    }
}
```

Iterating over `&Vec<T>` produces an iterator over `&T` (the same as the `.iter()` method).

Now we can see we can convert it into iterator, by either calling `.into_iter()` on `v` and then `.collect()` (which is what the `for` loop does), or replace `into_iter()` with `iter()` (which is more idiomatic since we're iterating over references):

```rust
fn sort_and_print(v: &Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>) {
    let mut v_copy: Vec<&Box<dyn Foo>> = v.iter().collect(); // You can omit the `&Box<dyn Foo>` and replace it with `_`, I put it here for clarity.
    v_copy.sort_by_key(|o| o.value());
    for val in v_copy {
        println!("{}", val.value());
    }
}
```

However, we still only have a copy of the reference (`&Box<dyn Foo>`). Why can't we just clone the vector?

If we try...

```rust
fn sort_and_print(v: &Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>) {
    let mut v_copy = v.clone();
    v_copy.sort_by_key(|o| o.value());
    for val in v_copy {
        println!("{}", val.value());
    }
}
```

...the compiler yell at us:

```rust
warning: variable does not need to be mutable
  --> src/main.rs:45:9
   |
45 |     let mut v_copy = v.clone();
   |         ----^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         help: remove this `mut`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_mut)]` on by default

error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*v_copy` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/main.rs:46:5
   |
45 |     let mut v_copy = v.clone();
   |         ---------- help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference: `&mut Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>`
46 |     v_copy.sort_by_key(|o| o.value());
   |     ^^^^^^ `v_copy` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
```

WHAT???????????

Well, let's try to specify the type. It can make the compiler smarter.

```rust
fn sort_and_print(v: &Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>) {
    let mut v_copy: Vec<Box<dyn Foo>> = v.clone();
    v_copy.sort_by_key(|o| o.value());
    for val in v_copy {
        println!("{}", val.value());
    }
}
```

Nope.

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:45:41
   |
45 |     let mut v_copy: Vec<Box<dyn Foo>> = v.clone();
   |                     -----------------   ^^^^^^^^^
   |                     |                   |
   |                     |                   expected struct `Vec`, found reference
   |                     |                   help: try using a conversion method: `v.to_vec()`
   |                     expected due to this
   |
   = note: expected struct `Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>`
           found reference `&Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>`
```

Well, let's use the compiler's suggestion:

```rust
fn sort_and_print(v: &Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>) {
    let mut v_copy: Vec<Box<dyn Foo>> = v.to_vec();
    v_copy.sort_by_key(|o| o.value());
    for val in v_copy {
        println!("{}", val.value());
    }
}
```

Grrr!!

```rust
error[E0277]: the trait bound `dyn Foo: Clone` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:45:43
   |
45 |     let mut v_copy: Vec<Box<dyn Foo>> = v.to_vec();
   |                                           ^^^^^^ the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `dyn Foo`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Clone` for `Box<dyn Foo>`
```

At least we now have some clues.

What happened here?

Well, like the compiler said, `dyn Foo` does not implement the `Clone` trait. Which means that neither does `Box<dyn Foo>`, and so is `Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>`.

However, `&Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>` actually *does* impl `Clone`. This is because you can have as many shared references as you want - shared (non-mutable) references are `Copy`, and every `Copy` is also `Clone`. Try it:

```
fn main() {
    let i: i32 = 123;
    let r0: &i32 = &i;
    let r1: &i32 = <&i32 as Clone>::clone(&r0);
}
```

So, when we write `v.clone()`, the compiler asks "is there a method named `clone()` that takes `self` of type `&Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>` (`v`)?" it first looks for such method on the `Clone` impl for `Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>` (because the `Clone::clone()` takes `&self`, so for `Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>` it takes `&Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>`). Unfortunately, such impl doesn't exist, so it does the magic of autoref (part the process of trying to adjust a method receiver in Rust, you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28552082/7884305)), and asks the same question for `&&Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>`. Now we *did* find a match - `<&Vec<Box<dyn Foo>> as Clone>::clone()`! So this is what the compiler calls.

What is the return type of the method? Well, `&Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>`. This will be the type of `v_copy`. Now we understand why when we specified another type, the compiler got crazy! We can also decrypt the error message when we didn't specify a type: we asked the compiler to call `sort_by_key()` on a `&Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>`, but this method requires a `&mut Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>` (`&mut [Box<dyn Foo>]`, to be precise, but it doesn't matter because `Vec<T>` can coerce to `[T]`)!

We can also understand the warning about a redundant `mut`: we never change *the reference*, so no need to declare it as mutable!

When we called [`to_vec()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.to_vec), OTOH, the compiler didn't get confused: `to_vec()` requires the vector's item to implement `Clone` (`where T: Clone`), which doesn't happen for `Box<dyn Foo>`. BOOM.

Now the solution should be clear: we just need `Box<dyn Foo>` to impl `Clone`.

Just?...

The first thing we may think about is to give `Foo` a supertrait `Clone`:

```rust
trait Foo: Clone {
    fn value(&self) -> i32;
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Bar { /* ... */ }
```

Not working:

```rust
error[E0038]: the trait `Foo` cannot be made into an object
  --> src/main.rs:33:31
   |
33 | fn sort_and_print(v: &Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>) {
   |                               ^^^^^^^ `Foo` cannot be made into an object
   |
note: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
  --> src/main.rs:1:12
   |
1  | trait Foo: Clone {
   |       ---  ^^^^^ ...because it requires `Self: Sized`
   |       |
   |       this trait cannot be made into an object...
```

Hmm, looks like [`Clone` indeed requires `Sized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/clone.rs.html#108). Why?

Well, because in order to clone something, we need to return itself. Can we return `dyn Foo`? No, because it can be of any size.

So, let's try to `impl Clone for Box<dyn Foo>` by hand (we can do that even though `Box` is not defined in our crate because it is a fundamental type and `Foo` is local (defined in our crate)).

```rust
impl Clone for Box<dyn Foo> {
    fn clone(self: &Box<dyn Foo>) -> Box<dyn Foo> {
        // Now... What, actually?
    }
}
```

*How can we even clone something that can be anything?* Clearly we need to forward it to someone else. Who else? Someone who knows how to clone this thing. A method on `Foo`?

```rust
trait Foo {
    fn value(&self) -> i32;
    fn clone_dyn(&self) -> Box<dyn Foo>;
}

impl Foo for Bar {
    fn value(&self) -> i32 {
        self.x
    }
    
    fn clone_dyn(&self) -> Box<dyn Foo> {
        Box::new(self.clone()) // Forward to the derive(Clone) impl
    }
}
```

NOW!

```rust
impl Clone for Box<dyn Foo> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        self.clone_dyn()
    }
}
```

IT WORKS!!

```rust
fn sort_and_print(v: &Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>) {
    let mut v_copy = v.clone();
    v_copy.sort_by_key(|o| o.value());
    for val in v_copy {
        println!("{}", val.value());
    }
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d6e871711146bc3f34d9710211b4a1dd

**Note:** The [dyn-clone](https://crates.io/crates/dyn-clone) crate from @dtonlay generalizes this idea.

Comment: "we can do that even though `Box` is not defined in our crate because it is a fundamental type" – this isn't quite true. The reason this is allowed is because `Foo` is defined in our crate, so there can't be any conflicting impelementation in upstream crates.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Of course, but if `Box` wasn't fundamental then `Box<dyn Foo>` wasn't local and we couldn't implement a foreign trait (`Clone`) for it. In this manner, `Box` is special. Edited the answer to clarify that.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was actually mixing things up a bit. You have been completely right. In fact, the standard library theoretically _could_ add a generic impl for `T: ?Sized` that would conflict with the impl here, but since `Box` is `#[fundamental]`, we are allowed to add this impl anyway.

Comment: @SvenMarnach The standard library is not allowed to define such impl _because_ it will break our code; in fact, [the definition of fundamental types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/glossary.html#fundamental-type-constructors) is that a type if funadmental if "implementing a blanket implementation over it is a breaking change."

Answer (score 1):

You can make `sort_and_print()` shorter using `Iterator::collect()`:

```
fn sort_and_print(v: &[Box<dyn Foo>]) {
    let mut v_copy: Vec<_> = v.iter().collect();
    v_copy.sort_by_key(|o| o.value());
    for val in v_copy {
        println!("{}", val.value());
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5bf453cbd394add48e8e5fcff46b6b50)

As an aside, accepting a vector by reference is usually better expressed as accepting a slice, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o), so the above answer accepts a slice.

You can make it even shorter by using the `sorted()` method from the `itertools` crate, or in this case its cousin `sorted_by_key()`:

```
use itertools::Itertools;

fn sort_and_print(v: &[Box<dyn Foo>]) {
    for val in v.iter().sorted_by_key(|o| o.value()) {
        println!("{}", val.value());
    }
}
```

You almost certainly don't want to clone the vector because it would involve a deep copy, i.e. cloning each `Box<dyn Foo>`, which is unnecessary, potentially expensive, as well as complicated (as explained in the other answer).

Comment: Even shorter is `Vec::from_iter(v)`. In Rust 2021 this is in the prelude, so I'm going to use this a lot more in the future.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Interestingly, the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html) state that `from_iter()` is "rarely called explicitly", making it sound like `.collect()` is the only intended way to use the trait. While the sentence is technically true (`from_iter()` *is* rarely called explicitly in current Rust), the implication is probably unintended. It is also in contradiction with  `FromIterator` being moved to the prelude, presumably to facilitate calling it directly. Do you think the "rarely called explicitly" remark should be omitted from the documentation?

Comment: I personally don't see a reason why `Vec::from_iter()` should be discouraged, and I agree that the comment sounds like it is meant to discourage the direct use of the function. In particular now that we can write `HashMap::<_, _>::from_iter([(key, value), ...])`, which in my opinion is not only more succinct than `[(key, value),...].into_iter().collect::<HashMap<_, _>>()`, but also somewhat more readable.

Comment: You are not the only one thinking the comment should be changed: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/90107